# Prerender.io with Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, prerender

I'm trying to use prerender.io with my Java based Play Framework application. I tried using [play-prerender](https://github.com/Jarlakxen/play-prerender) but I wasn't able to make an instance using Java (it requires Scala types as arguments such as Seq).

Is there an easy way to use Prerender.io with Play, using this library or using some other method?

Answer (score 0):

If Scala is in your classpath, you can use `JavaConversions` to convert a Java `List` to a Scala `Seq`. Otherwise, you could write your own wrapper of this class in Scala to provide a Java API. I believe it's fairly easy since it is pretty short.

Comment: JavaConversions does not seem to have a method to convert a java List to Seq, only the other way. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: A `Seq` can be an array or a `List` in Scala, as well as some other collections. You can always convert to an `Iterable` and then call `toList`. His class is not very well designed for Java users to be honest. He could have used a vararg to make it easier to access from Java